# JPA entities and table ids as string

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with MySQL, and there is a table that has data json data related to ids in other tables, rather than having intermediate tables

Currently there are 3 tables: Customers, Assets and Table XXX, which has 3 columns: id, name and myData. Here is a sample row:

```
1, "Some name",

[
    {"customerId": 1, "assets": {"active": [10, 12, 13], "inactive": [15, 16]}}",
    {"customerId": 2, "assets": {"active": [40, 42], "inactive": [19]}}"

]
```

BTW, I cannot change the design :(

Here are the entities:

```
@Table(name = "xxx")
class XXX {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   String myData;
}

@Table(name = "assets")
class Asset {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;
   private String name;
}

@Table(name = "customers")
class Customer {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;

   private String name;
}
```

However, I'd like entity XXX to correctly map the entities and have the customer and assets data, similar to this:

```
@Table(name = "xxx")
class XXX {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   //maybe some awesome annotation here?
   List<CustomerAssetsItem> customerAssetsItemsActive;

   //maybe some awesome annotation here?
   List<CustomerAssetsItem> customerAssetsItemsInactive;
}
```

where CustomerAssetsItem would look like:

```
class CustomerAssetsItem {
   Customer customer;
   List<Asset> assets;
}
```

Is it even possible with JPA? Or should I just create a new service that parses the json string, run all queries I ned to build the hierarchy?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you use as your database? Relational database or NoSQL database?

Comment: relational. MySQL

Comment: Can you please post your entities then? Because your minimal reproducible example does not provide enough information to actually replicate (or at least understand) the issue and help. Json does not provide any information between relationships.

Comment: You can do everthing. What is keeping you back?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, see this example: [JSON Attribute converter](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persist-json-object)

All you have to do is provide an `AttributeConverter` that maps the JSON String into your List or whatever.

On your entity you must annotate the converter class via `@Converter`

```
@Table(name = "xxx")
class XXX {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Long id;
   private String name;

   @Converter(converter = CustomerAssetsConverter.class)
   List<CustomerAssetsItem> customerAssetsItems;
}
```

And you have to provide your own converter, this is just a draft. You need to add a JSON object mapper. Also if you want to resolve the Customer id reference in the JSON you need your own deserializer that for `customerId: 1` mappings does a query to get that Customer. See this example: [Jackson Custom Deserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

You **may not want to resolve the references** because they can result in a lot of queries, also you very likely need to tweak a lot of settings to not end in an infinite loop.

I recommend enabling second level caching and using @Transactional appropriately.

```
@Converter
public class CustomerAssetsConverter implements AttributeConverter<CustomerAssetsItem, String> {

    //Add object mapper and repository

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(CustomerAssetsItem item) {
        String itemJSON = null;
        try {
            itemJSON = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(item);
        } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {

        }
        return itemJSON;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> convertToEntityAttribute(String itemJSON) {
        CustomerAssetsItem item = null;
        try {
            item = objectMapper.readValue(itemJSON, CustomerAssetsItem.class);
        } catch (final IOException e) {

        }
        return item;
    }
}
```